# Missing SimpleXML Parsing

Tags: php, simplexml

```
<?php
// load SimpleXML
$entry = new SimpleXMLElement('http://bit.ly/c3IqMF', null, true);

echo <<<EOF
<table>
        <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Image</th>                
        </tr>

EOF;
foreach($entry as $item) // 
{
        echo <<<EOF
        <tr>
                <td>{$item->title}</td>
                <td><img src="{$item->children('im', true)->image}"></td>       
        </tr>

EOF;
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

The above php works but somehow, I got 8 empty table entities above the result

```
<tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><img src=""></td>       
    </tr>
```

What's wrong with the code? How do I get rid of the empty table entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it now it gets the `<id>, <title>, <updated>` from the the start of the xml. Actually you needed all the `entry` entries in the xml. So it should be `$entry->entry`

```
foreach($entry->entry as $item) // 
{
        echo <<<EOF
        <tr>
                <td>{$item->title}</td>
                <td><img src="{$item->children('im', true)->image}"></td>       
        </tr>

EOF;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks
I don't have enough reputation to vote up, sorry :p

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you are approaching this the wrong way. Since it seems that you are trying to parse an Atom feed, try using something designed for that, like [Magpie RSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/). It will probably save you a lot of time.

Comment: Hi, I believe this can be done easily without Magpie RSS. I guess it would be my last effort. :D